# Hard reload in GWT with clear cache

Tags: java, javascript, caching, gwt, browser

I looked into the code of GWT. Window.Location.reload() doesn't seem to accept an argument and by default refreshes browser with cache. I wanted to reload the browser without cache. What are the ways to do in GWT? Something equivalent to Location.reload(true) of javascript in GWT. I'm fine with any solution which refreshes browser without cache.

Comment: Can you try this ? "Window.Location.replace("newurl");"

Comment: It might work since appending timestamp to the url will override cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using JSNI?

```
public static native void hardReload() /*-{
  $wnd.location.reload(true);
}-*/;
```